# '\' operator does not support floats?

Tags: vb.net, operators

```
Dim x As Integer = 1.8 \ 1
```

Error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit
>   conversions from 'Double' to 'Long'

What **Long**??

**EDIT:**

Apparently Visual Basic attempts to convert any floating-point numeric expression to Long. OK, this part is clear.

Now, I can use the

```
CType((Math.Round(myResultingSingle)), Integer)
```

but what for [MSDN tells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) that `\` operator supports all the types if in reality it supports only `Long` as *expression1* ?!...

Comment: What is your expected result? Also note that a conversion normally would use banker's rounding (if Option Strict is off).

Comment: @divo: x should be 2... or 1.. finally, I would like to eliminate the error, then see the (default) result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer division operator requires integral operands.  Two possible ways to do it:

- Dim x As Integer = CInt(1.8) \ 2
- Dim x As Integer = CInt(1.8 / 2)

Comment: so, only integral operands are supported by \, not all(including floating point), how pretends MSDN.

Comment: @serhio: As Grzegorz Gierlik pointed out, you can use a floating point number only with Option Strict Off. It's clearly stated on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

From [the MSDN page \ Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) :

> Before performing the division, Visual Basic attempts to convert any floating-point numeric expression to Long

*That* **Long**. Because **Double** to **Long** is a narrowing conversion, and `Option Strict` is on, you must explicitly ask for it to happen.

Comment: from the same MSDN page:
`Supported Types: All numeric types, including the unsigned and floating-point types and Decimal. ` in reality, only Long is supported as *expression1*.. :(

Comment: @serhio: Could it be that you are looking for the `/` operator instead?

Comment: @divo: as you can see, x is an Integer, so I need a integer division. x = 1 or 2...mdeas...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) (in Remarks section) is the answer:

> Before performing the division, Visual
>   Basic attempts to convert any
>   floating-point numeric expression to
>   Long. If Option Strict is On, a
>   compiler error occurs.

Comment: Visual Basic attempts to convert any floating-point numeric expression to Long... So what should I do? MSDN tells also that all types are supported, but in reality is `Long` only?!.

Comment: You have to convert double to integer type. See @nobugz answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093067/operator-does-not-support-floats/2093386#2093386